# CRM 2011 - Import Solution getting error Unable to load plug-in assembly

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2011

Here's my story:  I've imported my CRM 4 solution to CRM 2011.  Most things look OK, plug-ins mostly work.  This import process was done through the CRM Deployment Manager.

Step 2 I wanted to test building a Solution, adding all my customizations to it, export it, and import it to a second organization on the same server.

Its gotten fairly close (its a HUGE improvement over CRM 4).  But its failing when it goes to load my plug-in assembly.  The CRM Trace and event log aren't providing me any more help than the solution import log file:

> Failure   0x80044191  Unable to load
>   plug-in assembly.

My assembly is deployed to disk so its available.  I tried unzipping the solution file, and adding my assembly in the solution hierarchy but that didn't help.

Is it because they're CRM 4 plug-ins?  Must they be updated to be imported in CRM 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up being I was referencing an assembly not in the GAC of the new server.  Wasn't related to solutions per-say and I couldn't register directly with the plugin registration tool either (though that gave me more information).  So if you see this I recommend trying to register the assembly using the plugin registration tool to get better information.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to register your old plugins; upgrading plugins isn't required.  Have you tried registering the plugin to database instead of disk? Are you able to register this plugin against your 4.0 environment?

See [Upgrade Plug-ins and Custom Workflow Activities to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334459.aspx) for more info about upgrading if you decide to try that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you try to import your solution in new organization of MS CRM2011 it is throwing exception because MS CRM4.0 plug-ins are using a library "microsoft.crm.sdk.dll" which does not exist in the GAC. Here is a workaround for the registration of MS CRM4 Plug-ins in MS CRM2011 http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crmdevelopment/thread/d3ce2b89-e8d3-4334-9117-fda2193e03a8

Answer (score 1):

Does your plugin assembly have any dependencies (except the obvious microsoft.crm.*)? If so, try to ILMerge everything into one big DLL and deploy it to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  We once ILMerge'd things, but since we've moved to Disk deployment (we don't support CRM Online anyway) we really love the better build times without ILMerge.

Comment: That's so, but then you have to be veeeery careful about where you keep your dependencies... we used to spend endless hours trying to herd all those dlls in a proper place and finally decided that extra build time is a lesser evil.

Comment: BTW, ILMerging also prevents version conflicts on dependencies - useful if you deploy several plugins build by different people at widely different time against almost, but not quite the same set of dependencies.

Comment: I know what you're talking about.  Usually turns out OK if you do a re-build.  Considering adding a custom build step which merges everything needed for the Server\bin\assembly folder in a single folder (not so different than building ILMerge I guess).  

Anyway, atthe start of this question I WAS ILMerging, and removed it to help simplify the things in search of my eventual solution.

Its one of those things that would be fairly easy to add back in if I felt a need to.  I've found the trick is to keep your workflow activities using the old merge name so compiled workflows still work.